# Combobox value does not stay as previous value when not re-set WPF

Tags: wpf, view, combobox, binding, propertychanged

I have read related issues, but my problem still occurs.
I am trying to choose a database connection from the combobox and if it fails to connect, switch the combo value back to the previous one.
Code:

```
 public string SelectedConnStringValue
    { 
        get { return _selectedConnStringValue; }
        set
        {
            if (!DBConn.Instance.Open(value))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Attempt failed", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                DBConn.Instance.Close();
                _selectedConnStringValue = value;
                DefaultConf.Instance.DefaultConnectionStringName = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedConnStringValue");
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
```

XAML

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="serversComboBox" SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="120" Margin="672,0,0,0" Height="25" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Connections}" Text="{Binding SelectedConnStringValue}"/>
```

The problem is when I try to put wrong connectionstring. I want then to reselect the combo value to the previous one, thus not updating it at all, but it does not work. I have tried to do         RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedConnStringValue");
        instead of OnPropertyChanged, but it does nothing

Comment: Bind the SelectedItem property of the combobox instead of the text property.

Comment: Okay, but then I get the full connectionstring, not the "Name" property, but I will probably find the answer how to get it

Comment: If you set `SelectedValuePath="Name"`, you should bind `SelectedValue` (not `SelectedItem`) to an appropriate string property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SelectionChanged` event and assign the `SelectedItem` to previous selectedItem.

Properties are binded to Dependency property and value is already changed in `Dependency Property` in the given scenario. The setter will not be able to revert the value in `control/combobox` unless you assign it again.

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        var selctedItem = comboBox?.SelectedItem as TestModel;
        if (selctedItem != null && selctedItem.Equals("Test2"))
        {
            comboBox.SelectedItem = previousSelected;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, I was hoping that it is possible to do it in the properties, but eventually I did what you suggested